# Embedding subprocessed widgets in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, multiprocessing

Perhaps I'm easily biting off more than I can chew here, but I have a piece of software that is at times image heavy and often will be run by visual effects artists with reasonably power workstations. Even though I consider myself to be only "somewhat" experienced in PyQt as far as usage of divvying out as much processing of images and the like out to QThreads, I still seem to have hit some sort of wall which can either be:

- The result of trying to do too much (likely)
- Not [handling widget population](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109398/creating-a-custom-qtreewidgetitem-with-an-embedded-qwidget)(shameless plug) in the most efficient way possible due mostly to ignorance (more likely), or
- Limits of PyQt (least likely).

What I'd like to try, *like nobody before me,* is to mimic the efficiency of Google Chrome in it's multiprocessing capabilities. However my only knowledge of separate processes is Popen and reading its stdout through pipes in Windows.

My question, in layman's terms:

- **Is it possible to subprocess the rendering of widgets and wrap than inside a generic widget, such as a QMainWindow?**

I suppose the best example in old HTML parlance would be iframes.

Is this in the realm of the doable? Is it overkill? Are there examples of such magic in the world? Any and all help would be great!

Comment: Qt requires that all the GUI code should be run in a single thread. But that's rarely a problem. What sort of widgets do you have in mind that might be a little 'heavy'?

Comment: See the shamelessly plugged link in the op. Essentially its a qtreewidget full of custom widgets with buttons, labels and pixmaps abound, and there could be hundreds of these. Plus lots of other widgets with pixmaps populated from an http server and sql db, to name a few.

Comment: A `QTreeWidget` with lots of items full of custom widgets is certainly not a good idea. Aside from the rendering issue, you are creating tons of `QWidget`s that will essentially consume lots of memory. You should consider a `QTreeView` with a delegate to paint those.

Comment: And therein lies the ignorance of such things. I'll shall do some googles. Thanks Avaris.